# How to add a node between 2 child divs of a parent node-EXTJS

Tags: extjs

I want to add an element between 2 child elements inside a parent node. Following is the HTML for that:

html:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  // I want to insert <span class="child2"></span> here
  <div class="child3"></div>
</div>
```

I tried:

```
var newNode = document.createElement("span");
var a = Ext.select("child3")
Ext.select("parent").insertBefore(newNode,a );
```

this does not do anything. ideas how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var referenceNode=document.body.querySelector('.child1'),
newNode=document.createElement('span');
newNode.innerHTML='child2';
newNode.setAttribute('class','child2');
referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">child1</div>
  <div class="child3">child3</div>
</div>
```